# Python regex: split by repeated punctuation marks

Tags: python, regex

```
How????are!!!you
```

I'd like to split the string into `['How','are','you']`.

I've tried the following regex:

```
\?*|\!*
```

which does not work. However, the following regex works:

```
\?+|\!+
```

Anyone explain this to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> re.split(r'[?!]*', 'How????are!!!you')
['How', 'are', 'you']
```

As for why `\?*|\!*` doesn't work, just look at what `re.findall` finds:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\?*|\!*', 'How????are!!!you')
['', '', '', '????', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

The alternation always takes the first branch if possible. `re.split` tries to only split by nonempty matches, so you end up splitting by `?` but not `!` (since `\?*` will match any empty string, `\!*` will never match in a non-overlapping fashion).